# How many possible arrangements of stickers can I have?

Tags: combinatorics

I have infinitely many mickey, goofy, donald, and spongebob stickers. How many different assortments of stickers can I have if I can only choose 8 stickers?

Comment: obviously infinitely many...

Comment: oops, forgot something, sorry

Comment: So if the amount of each type of sticker was a,b,c, and d, then a+b+c+d=8. Thus it's $\binom{8+4-1}{4}=330?$

Comment: Yes, that's right.  This is what  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is designed to handle.  If you go through that, I think you'll get that the answer is $\binom {8+4-1}8=165$.